# finding the maximum records based on the maximum date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a table EmployeeDetails

```
DeptID   |       workDate       |  percentage
------------------------------------------
1           06/07/16 10:10:10      10%
1           07/07/16 11:11:10      20%
2           06/07/16 09:10:10      5%
2           07/07/16 08:10:10      3%
3           06/07/16 10:10:10      15%
4           07/07/16 11:10:10      20%
```

Could you please help me to find a sql query that obtains the finding the maximum datetime of 'workDate' then based on the 'workDate' get the corresponding record for each department.

Expected output:

```
DeptID    | workDate |       percentage 
1       07/07/16 11:11:10     20% 
2       07/07/16 08:10:10     3% 
3       06/07/16 10:10:10    15% 
4       07/07/16 11:10:10    20%
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: please show your required output

Comment: DeptID   |       workDate       |  percentage
--------------------------------------------------
1           07/07/16 11:11:10      20%
2           07/07/16 08:10:10      3%
3           06/07/16 10:10:10      15%
4           07/07/16 11:10:10      20%

Comment: Can an employee have two records with the exact same `workDate` value?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. Inner join will help in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDetails
(
    DeptID int
    ,workDate datetime
    ,percentage varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #EmployeeDetails
SELECT 1,'06/07/16 10:10:10','10%'
UNION
SELECT 1,'07/07/16 11:11:10','20%'
UNION
SELECT 2,'06/07/16 09:10:10','5%'
UNION
SELECT 2,'07/07/16 08:10:10','3%'
UNION
SELECT 3,'06/07/16 10:10:10','15%'
UNION
SELECT 4,'07/07/16 11:10:10','20%'

SELECT   T1.* 
FROM     #EmployeeDetails T1
JOIN    (SELECT DeptID,MAX(workDate) AS max_workdate
         From #EmployeeDetails
         GROUP BY DeptID) T2 
ON       T1.DeptID = T2.DeptID AND T1.workDate = T2.max_workdate
ORDER BY T1.DeptID
```